# SCNPhysicsBody Change Centre of Mass

Tags: game-physics, scenekit

I using SceneKit and trying to create a SCNPhysicsBody where the mass is not even distributed.  I found the following [solution for SKPhysicsBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664505/skphysicsbody-change-center-of-mass), which creates two nodes of different masses and connects them using a SKPhysicsJoint.  However SCNPhysics don't have a Fixed joint type, it only has Hinge, Ball and Socket and Slider.

I have tried using a Hinge joint connecting the two nodes down the Y axis at the point the nodes touch, but this generated an unstable object when the two nodes try and occupy the same space.

Does anyone has any ideas of a solution to this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach ought to work in SceneKit. Make two nodes of different masses, and attach them to a parent node at different positions.